# Where can I get information about how is vehicle Make/Model and Parts Database?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, database-design

I'm designing a autoparts database. I'm having a hard time with this design. I was watching this site:

http://www.rockauto.com/catalog/raframecatalog.php

MAKE > YEAR > MODEL > MOTOR > CATEGORIES.

And well I think I need to add that table to the design. Here is the current:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5770/database-design-for-an-autoparts-store

I'm looking for sites where describes how would be organize these data, or what is the best way to create the tables for this area. I think is complicated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How I might to create the tables for a vehicle database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7988002/how-i-might-to-create-the-tables-for-a-vehicle-database)

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/q/7989894/562459. Ask once. Have some patience.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should look into database normalization:

Normalization helps you understand how to represent data in a consistent way, which represents the relationships between teh data.

Links:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/An-Introduction-to-Database-Normalization/