# How I might to create the tables for a vehicle database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, database-design

MAKE - MODEL - YEAR - MOTOR are the entities. I'm working with these 4 entities, but I haven't found the best design (I guess is wrong)

```
Motor
- MotorID
- MotorName

Model
- ModelID
- MotorID
- ModelName

Year
- YearID
- YearName
- ModelID

Make
- MakeID
- MakeName
- YearID
```

I was watching this website to investigate how is organized: http://www.rockauto.com/catalog/raframecatalog.php

I'm still having doubts about the design fot these four tables.

Comment: Not sure that "motor" is something that should have it's own top level entity given the short number of things you are collecting.  After all, a LOT of motors are specific to either a particular model or even a particular model/year.

Comment: yearID? i hope motors wont made at sametime

Comment: Interesting enough, Chris, this i absolutely not the case. Engines (Motors) are quite often even not build by the same manufacturer (check: Lotus, Alfa Romeo). The engine in the upcoming Alfa 4c is the same as in the Giulietta... which is a Fiat standard Engine.

Comment: Take a look at [VIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_Identification_Number).

Answer (score 2):

So consider what makes up the database

Vehicles / Motor which would contain

1. An identifier (registration plate?)
2. The manufacturer
3. The model
4. The year it was made in.

Now, without normalisation that's fine, but you can see there will be duplicated information in there, so you'd extract that one by one. First you'd take out manufacturer into a separate table, so now Motor would become

1. An identifier
2. The manufacturer ID (a foreign key to the manufacturer table)
3. The model
4. The year it was made in.

The manufacturer table would hold.

1. The manufacturer ID
2. The manufacturer name.

Now you can look at model. But a model is really only made by a single manufacturer, so, hmm, we could do this for the model

1. The model ID
2. The model description
3. The manufacturer ID (foreign key to the manufacturer table)

And motor would become

Motor would become

1. An identifier
2. The model ID (foreign key to the manufacturer table)
3. The year it was made in.

Personally, I'm not sure I would normalise the year into a table of its own. The year would be an integer field, and the ID column would probably also be an integer field, so you're not saving much ...

Comment: I might be tempted to normalize the year out if you were going to keep track on when years started (not on a Jan boundary) like you were going to track plate issues in the UK

Comment: Ah that's an interesting point, if it were a month/year combination of when the plates were issued, like US states, that would be another good reason.

Answer (score 0):

My view is that you have a vehicle which is a composite of the following aspects

```
Manufacturer
Model Name
Model Variant
Engine
Year

So you'd have the following tables

Manufacturer (ManufacturerID, Name, ParentCompanyID (references ManufacturerID))
Model_Name (Model_NameID, Name)
Model_Variant (Model_VariantID, name)
Engine (EngineID, Name, ManufacturerID) - this is because a vehicle can have an engine by a different manufacturer
Year (YearID, Year)

Vehicle (VehicleID, ManufacturerID, Model_NameID, Model_VariantID, Engine_ID, YearID)
```

You would then have the components of a vehicle be marked as distinct as a collection so your don't insert a vehicle twice.

Please note that these are incomplete tables and are just to give you the bare bones of an idea. You should probably with manufacturer mark if they are a regional variant so you can adequately distinguish between a Ford Focus for UK sale and one for US sale.

Answer (score 0):

Without adding any extra complexity to the RockAuto site it appears to structure it's tree view as make-year-model-variant but 'year' doesn't really have any attributes or children or parents, it's more like an attribute of model.

```
make - id, name
model - id, make.id, year, name
variant - id, model.id, name

make->model is 1:m
model->variant is 1:m
model->variant is 1:m
```

You might consider having the model with a date range, but then the same would apply to each variant as well. Once you start adding any further complexity you'll be down to VIN numbers .

Answer (score -2):

actually if this isn't a homework task (which I suspect It is) I would use some orm tool and take the results (or tweak them), actually you could also do that with homework - but i'll guess that would be cheating

anyway I would guess a quite different table mapping, guessing similiar too @jamieDainton that you are missing an entity that ties it all together like vehicle